# Resize Swift Playgrounds live view when device is in different orientations

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, sprite-kit, swift-playground

I'm trying to make a simple spritekit game run within Swift Playgrounds on an iPad.

So far, I have this code:

```
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 600)
let view = SKView(frame: frame)


let scene = GameScene(size: frame.size)
//gamescene, of course, is the spritekit scene that exists in a different file.
view.presentScene(scene)
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

Running this in the usual orientation (iPad sideways with code on the left and the live view on the right) looks completely normal. However, when I turn the iPad vertically (code on the bottom and live view on the top), the scene appears squished vertically. This squishing happens identically whether I turn the iPad while the game is running or before running the game.

I imagine this is because of my hardcoded frame variable, but I've seen others able to have their playground run with the correct sizing regardless of orientation (even if it's harder to resize while the app is running). How is this done?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to update your frame,  even though you are rotating it,  your GameScene frame will remain landscape, thus causing the problem

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Interesting. What would be the easiest way to go about updating the frame when the orientation changes?

Comment: in playgrounds I have no idea,  there has to be a way to capture orientation

Comment: Never mind, I've fixed the problem. Setting the scene's scene.scaleMode property allowed it to resize whenever the orientation or arrangement changed (I used SKSceneScaleMode.resizeFill, but that might not work best for everyone).